# Calling Non Virtual Method from child class

Tags: c++, class, function, polymorphism, parent

I know based on polymorphism that you cannot call a non virtual function/method

Ex:

```
class Entity
{
public: 
    Entity() { health = 10; }
    void DisplayHealth() { std::cout << health << std::endl; }
protected: 
    int health;
}; 

class Player : public Entity
{

};

class Enemy : public Entity
{
    void SetHealth(int n) { health = n; }
};

int main()
{
    Entity *instance = new Enemy(); 
    instance->SetHealth(1); // Error
    return 0;
}
```

so what I have come up with to counteract that is do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Entity *instance = new Enemy(); 
    Enemy e = *(Enemy*)instance; 
    e.SetHealth(1); 
    instance = &e; 
}
```

This works fine for my needs but I'm wondering if this is the "correct" way of doing it. Is there a more efficient way to call a child class method using Polymorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Entity *instance = new Enemy(); 
Enemy e = *(Enemy*)instance;
```

creates a new Enemy object and then assigns what is pointed to by instance to it. Which is redundant. and then

```
instance = &e;
```

causes memory leak because you just lost the pointer to `new Enemy()` and you have not deleted it.

---

```
int main()
{
    Entity *instance = new Enemy(); 
    Enemy *e = static_cast<Enemy*>(instance);  
          ^^ 
    e->SetHealth(1); 
}
```

==================================================================================

==================================================================================

However seeing as `Health` is a member of base class `Entity`, You can just move the `setHealth` function to Entity and be done with it.

```
class Entity
{
public: 
    Entity() { health = 10; }
    void DisplayHealth() { std::cout << health << std::endl; }
    void SetHealth(int n) { health = n; }
protected: 
    int health;
};

int main()
{
    Entity *instance = new Enemy(); 
    instance->SetHealth(1); // Not Error Anymore
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd add setter function to Entity as health is in Entity. then call it through public `Entity::SetHealth()`

Comment: @billz good point. Donno why OP wanted to do this specifically. But you are right at lease I should suggest it.

Comment: That's not what I want to do in my program it was just a simple example to explain the concept of what I wanted to do but that's for the enlightenment. I in fact did this method firstly and reverted back to the method I posted but I wasn't even thinking of memory leaks x_x. Stupid thinking oh well thanks for the help

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy then go with the `static_cast<>`. I think that is what you need.